# Max http request body using postman

Tags: http, https, postman, http-headers

I am trying to send a file over https using postman to a server. The file is over 80MB and I see that postman sends data in request body of the https frame and the max size of data sent in one https request is 8k. Is it possible to increase this to 16k or 32k?

REgards